# PreferenceCategory in CardView

Tags: java, android, preference

I create an activity program settings using `PreferenceFragment`. I need every `CategoryPreference` inside `CardView`, as shown in the picture. I searched on Google but didn't find anything useful. If anyone has any ideas I would be very grateful[image]

---

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?